# Computing distance with relation to other rows (using R)

Tags: r, group-by

I have a set of columns with numerical values that describe a given object (row) in some 5 dimensional space. I want to compute the distance for each object from a fixed object at various times. I can `group_by` time and perform the desired computation. The issue is that I'm not sure how to do the computation. I want to use the Euclidean distance (squared) to measure the distance between these objects in 5 dimensional space. So clearly at each time, the reference object should be 0 distance from itself.

The metric should look like distance from object x to object Reference is

(x1 - Reference1)^2 + (x2 - Reference2)^2 + ....

I'm VERY new to working in R (and programming in general), so I was hoping this exercise would help me learn; I apologize if my question is not appropriate, I'm new.

My data looks like

[image]

Comment: There is an interesting question in here someplace, but I can't quite figure it out.  Can you provide a table of example input data, and another table of the desired output?  Don't need 45 rows.  3 to 5 will do nicely.

Comment: Install the `fields` package and use function `rdist`. Put sample data in your original question, not in a comment. Create small data frames that show what you are doing and include the output from `dput()` for each of those data frames.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use these packages to post the question?  I'm extremely green at programming generally.  I don't mind if you edit my post, I'm not lazy, just not sure how to do what you're describing.

Comment: I'm suggesting you use the function `rdist` in package `fields` as an answer to your question. The function takes two matrices and computes the distances between all of the rows in the first against all of the rows in the second. The details are in the manual page for the function `?rdist`.

Comment: Please don't include an image of data (or code): it breaks screen-readers and SEO, and many people choose to not even attempt to transcribe the data you have on your console. As suggested in my other comment, please use `dput(x)` where `x` is *just big enough* to get the point across, showing variability (in `time`) and sufficient data (3-5 columns of numbers to "distance" across).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distances from rows to other rows can be done in base R with this:

```r
mtx <- structure(c(2.8, 6.4, 1.7, 3.2, 24.2, 25.5, 5.4, 16.2, 15.6, 25.1, 8.6, 15.4, 0.7, 0.8, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.04, 0.2), .Dim = 4:5)

outer(seq_len(nrow(mtx)), seq_len(nrow(mtx)),
      function(a, b) rowSums((mtx[a,] - mtx[b,])^2))
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
# [1,]   0.0000 105.0000 404.0136  64.2500
# [2,] 105.0000   0.0000 698.9696 190.9500
# [3,] 404.0136 698.9696   0.0000 165.3156
# [4,]  64.2500 190.9500 165.3156   0.0000
```

Granted, you only need to calculate (less-than) half of that matrix, since the diagonal is always zero and the upper/lower triangles of it are mirrors, but this gives you what you need. For instance, the distances from the third row to all other rows are in the third row (and third column).

If all you need is one row compared to all others, then

```r
rowSums((mtx[rep(3,nrow(mtx)),] - mtx)^2)
# [1] 404.0136 698.9696   0.0000 165.3156
```

The `mtx[rep(3,nrow(mtx)),]` creates a same-size matrix so that subtraction works seamlessly.

Comment: That's great.  And want if I only want one of the rows from this distance matrix and couldn't care less about the other values?

Comment: Do you mean an over-engineered (but direct-translation of the above) with `outer(3, seq_len(nrow(mtx)), function(a, b) rowSums((mtx[a,] - mtx[b,])^2))`?

Comment: I guess my question is: If I use either of these last two comments of your will this speed up the computations?

Comment: If you want to squeeze even more speed, then `rowSums((mtx[rep(3,nrow(mtx)-1),] - mtx[-3,])^2)` (doesn't attempt to calculate distance with the same row). But that's about as fast as one can get (short of C/C++ code) to determine the distance between a row and all (other) rows. How large is your real matrix that you're concerned about improving the runtime?

Comment: Around 8000 rows before I group by time.  I assume I can apply your code within the group_by(time) as well? I have no clue if that's "a lot" but I would suspect that 8k rows is tiny.

Comment: I don't know. I believe this code works on a frame as well (quick testing confirms this), but I don't know/understand the rest of your "5-dim structure" to be able to say yes-or-no to that. Please add the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is enough of your data to demonstrate your grouping (so you should include `time` as well as a handful of your to-be-distanced columns). Since you tagged your question with `group_by`, it is sorely lacking anything about the grouping concept or overall structure/flow.

Comment: (And yes, I think 8k rows is not "big" from the perspective of distance-calculation. :-)

Comment: Could I please look at my most recent update to the question. I have taken into account the grouping concern you raised... I'm still having a tough time using your suggestion, so I updated my question.

Comment: So as you can see I want to group by the value in the first column and compute the distances with respect to Kate.  Also when I tried using your previous code the column of names caused issues.

Comment: Perhaps modify my `rowSums` code to ignore the name column, perhaps `rowSums((mtx[rep(3,nrow(mtx)),-1] - mtx[,-1])^2)`.